# Can I "fix" heading levels in rST on GitHub?

Tags: github, markdown, restructuredtext, github-flavored-markdown

On GitHub, in a `.md` file I'm able to specify heading levels that are respected in they way they are displayed on there, but my `.rst` files are not: the "highest" level heading is treated as a level 1 heading,

For example,

```
## Heading

Stuff

## Sub-heading

More stuff
```

in a `.md` will treat the first as a second-level heading and the second as a third-level heading, while its equivalent (e.g as generated by `pandoc`),

```
Heading
-------

Stuff

Sub-heading
~~~~~~~~~~~

More stuff
```

is treated as a first-level and second-level headings.

Is there a way to overcome this? Can I "fix" the heading level in rST, at as GitHub interprets it?

Comment: No, this is not possible -- even in Docutils outside of GitHub this is not possible. One of the many reasons I dislike rST.

Comment: Sounds line an answer then. (I agree, Markdown is MUCH better, but I'm stuck with .rst for this project: a PyPi package. I wish Python and Docutils would switch to Markdown!)

Comment: Interesting side note: As the developer of Python-Markdown I considered switching the parser to use Docutils' document object under the hood (it would allow Markdown to be an addon to Docutils among other things), but it was this very issue that ended that pursuit. If you are interested, see more [here](https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown/issues/420#issuecomment-117675683)

Comment: @Waylan: Feel free to answer.

Comment: I've added an answer with a few more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

Docutils does not allow header levels to be skipped. In fact, it will crash hard on inconsistently nested levels. Additionally, here is no hard rule for which characters in the ReST syntax represent which level. It is simply assumed that they appear in the order they are found (the inconsistency comes when you step back up, then down again -- it is assumed that you use the same pattern going back down). Therefore, the first header is always a level 1 header (`<h1>`) regardless of which character you use. However, in Markdown the levels are explicit in the syntax. If a user starts with `### Header`, then that first header in the document must be level 3 (`<h3>`). Under the hood, Docutils has no mechanism for retaining that info. It only knows whether a header is the "next higher" or "lower" level in consecutive order.